# exponential equation (solve for x)

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-function

We started review in my calculus class and I have mostly forgotten everything about exponential equations.

$$ e^{-x} * (3e^{2x}-(5/4))^{1/2} = e^x $$

Would x just equal 0, when -x+x=0 (two sides of the $e$ exponents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $e^x$ and squaring both sides gives you

$$3e^{2x}-\frac{5}{4} = e^{4x}.$$

Setting $y=e^{2x}$, you get a quadratic equation $y^2 - 3y + \frac{5}{4}=0$, and you should be able to solve for $y$ and then $x$ from there.

Comment: Note that $y > 0$, so if the quadratic has a negative root, it must be discarded. In this case it doesn't (because 5/4 > 0), but it would happen if the -5/4 term were positive.